# How to add an variable in .env file which contain #?

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, dotenv

I want to define KEY=qwerty#1234 in .env file in create-react-app but it ignores everything after #. I have tried KEY="qwerty#1234" but it did not work.
So, How can I assign this?

Actual variable in .env file:

```
API_END_POINT=/try/xyz_abc
ADMIN_KEY="Z3+{Ef/@pJ*Axc-WW`v5#RT45%<1:V(3"
API_SOMETHING=/xyz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#` starts a comment

add quotes -> `KEY='qwerty#1234'`

Comment: It is my bad. I have to use single quotes. now it is working fine. Thanks.
Your previous answer was correct.

Comment: Perfect. As you can imagine, I did not have time to properly test it

Answer (score 1):

You could surround it with quotes?

```
KEY="qwerty#1234"
```